# How to preprocess image before feeding into LeNet CNN in Caffe?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, caffe

I am having issue in feeding my own image into LeNet using Caffe library. I have deployed and initialised the weight obtained through training with no difficulties. As the net is trained using input size of 28x28, I tried resizing the input image to 28x28 and feed into the deployed LeNet, but it gave me *"unhashable numpy array"* error.

Not only that, I also tried to transpose it with `img = img.transpose(img, (2,0,1))` after resizing but it gave me *"TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"*

Below are the python codes I tried so far in pre-processing my image :

```
img = caffe.io.load_image('number5.png')
img = caffe.io.resize_image(img, (28,28), interp_order=3)
img = img.transpose(img, (2,0,1))
```

I am a beginner in using Caffe and still in the process of learning. I hope someone can give me some example or insights in how to pre-process an image before feeding into the net.

Thank You.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this instead:

```
img = img.transpose((2,0,1))
```

Comment: i get the same error: unhashable type: numpy.ndarray when trying to feed it to the net

Answer (score 0):

You can use `caffe.io.Transformer`
This is used to preprocess caffe 'data' blob.
Define it as

```
transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data':net.blobs['data'].data.shape})
transformer.set_transpose('data',(2,0,1))
```

then you can,

```
img = caffe.io.load_image('number5.png')
img = caffe.io.resize_image(img, (28,28), interp_order=3)
img_transposed=transformer.preprocess('data',img)
```